# Lazy loading initialization using hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I'm writing my apllication using Spring MVC + Hibernate.
I have 2 entities: order and items(order items).

Order entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Column(name = "time")
private long time;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private List<Item> items;
```

Item entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Order.class)
private Order order;

@Column
private int count;
```

I want to list orders in page '/orders', and order's detail in page '/orders/{id}/view'.

In my DAOImpl i write code below:

```
public List<Order> view() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Order.class)
            .addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.desc("time"))
            .list();
}
```

This code returns a list of all orders. But if I try see order's detail I have exception: *org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ru.drupo.order.domain.Order.items, could not initialize proxy - no Session*.

There are duplicates of orders in list if I add to order's entity **fetch = FetchType.EAGER**. But order's detail shows correctly.

How I can initialize lazy loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in transaction (within active session) use `Hibernate.initialize(order.getItems())` to initialize non-hydrated entities or collections.